# Why do I have positive $R^2$ if $y$ and $\hat{y}$ are negatively correlated?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

I am running a multi regression

```
y~lm(x1 + x2 + x3 -1)
```

i.e., no interception

I built the model and calculated $\hat{y}$ which is $\sum(\beta_{1} x1+ \beta_{2}*x2 + \beta_{3}*x3)$

I compute $R^2$ as $\frac{SSR}{SST_O}$. It is positive, so I thought the model is working.

however, I found that $y$ and $\hat{y}$ are negatively correlated.

I don't know how to explain this. Naively I though y and $\hat{y}$ should be positively correlated when I see a positive $R^2$

Comment: I have trouble imagining a situation where the dependent variable $y$ and the fit $\hat{y}$ are *negatively* correlated. (These *are* your DV and fit, right?) Can you post a picture showing $\hat{y}$ against $y$, or even your full dataset (the output of `dput()`)?

Comment: @Stephan I suspect you won't have much trouble finding an example if we  draw your attention to the lack of intercept in the model :-).  Try this out for instance: `n <- 50;
with(data.frame(x=1:n, y=1:n - n, x2=rnorm(n), x3=rnorm(n)), {
  c('R-squared'=summary(fit <- lm(y ~ . - 1, X))$r.squared,
        Correlation=cor(y, predict(fit)))
})`

Comment: @whuber: ouch. Thank you. I learned something new today. Now I can't unlearn it...

Comment: The question @whuber is answering in his comment is how can y and y^ be negatively correlated?  That is not the question asked by the OP.

Comment: @Michael Would you please tell us, then, what *your* interpretation is of the question "I found that $y$ and $\hat y$ are negatively correlated ... I don't know how to explain this ... when I see a positive $R^2$."  Please note that it is not that case that $R^2$ is always positive!  (Run the code in my comment for a concrete example.)

Comment: As defined as sum of squares due to the model/ total sum of squares $R^2$ is always nonnegative and between 0 and 1.  When you have this special case of no intercept regression and it is a poorly fit model  it has been shown and  we have discussed it before. that you can calculate a negative value.  The OP said here that he got a positive $R^2$ and was surprised because y and y^ negatively correlated. So you can calculate a total sum of squares that is less than the error sum of squares.